# CSS image as background with overlaying gradient color

Tags: html, css

I have a picture as background of a list-element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/WUe2P/14/)

I'd like to have a gradient overlaying the background-image of the list-item which should be transparent.

css foreground, overlaying the image should be like this:

```
.listItem{
    background: linear-gradient(white, black);
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

I can't wrap a div around the list-element, because the framework doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WUe2P/28/) .. Try this in your **CSS**

```
.listItem{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEtKrXuUIiURHP7PFGY_cdYDXyuWhilTgWHkJxZRWAt3-tlSy6epfAAFQQ') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

you can use **RGBA** colors which are much better than using normal colors with `opacity` property

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thx, that's it. I'd never figured that out by myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `image url` at the last

```
.listItem{
    background: linear-gradient(white, black), url('/img/sampleImage.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```